# Python package isnt upgraded despite running `conda install`

Tags: python, conda

I have a conda enviroment called `Vik`. One of the packages installed is `TBB` (`tbb=2018.0.5`). I want to upgrade to  version `2019.5` or later because my code returns this warning. `NumbaWarning: The TBB threading layer requires TBB version 2019.5 or later`
Thus, I went on and installed the latest `TBB` (at least this is what I believe). I havent kept the original message log but It looked normal to me. I am under the impression that the package was successfully installed. When I try to install it again this is what I get

```
(base) C:\Windows\system32>conda activate Vik
(Vik) C:\Windows\system32>conda install -c conda-forge tbb
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
# All requested packages already installed.
```

but it appears that i am still calling the old version `2018.0.5`. The numba warning that I need to upgrade `tbb` is still there when I run my application and `conda env export -n Vik > environment.yml` generates the following list. At the bottom of the list below you can clearly see that the package hasnt been updated. Note that the package doesnt appear under the pip section of the `environment.yml` shown below, hence it should be a conda package.

What am I doing wrong?

```
name: Vik
channels:
  - anaconda
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - anyio=3.2.0=py37h03978a9_0
  - argon2-cffi=20.1.0=py37he774522_1
  - async_generator=1.10=py37h28b3542_0
  - attrs=21.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - babel=2.9.1=pyh44b312d_0
  - backcall=0.2.0=py_0
.....
.....
.....
  - sqlite=3.35.3=h2bbff1b_0
  - tbb=2018.0.5=he980bc4_0
  - terminado=0.9.1=py37_0
```

Comment: Try `conda install tbb==2019.5` (or another specific version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `conda install -c conda-forge tbb` directive translates to the imperative

> *With the channel **conda-forge** prioritized, ensure that the currently activated environment has some version of `tbb` installed.*

Since `tbb` is already installed, that directive is already satisfied.

If you want a newer version, either use `conda update -c conda-forge tbb` or specify a version, e.g., `conda install -c conda-forge tbb=2021`.